# Is there a way for the output text from a pop-up text field to re-write a label on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project titled "apple pie" and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way for a user to enter their name on a pop-up alert, I coded, and for that name, that they typed, to appear or re-write a blue background label on the game.

This is all the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var treeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var correctWordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var letterButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    //Player name output to blue label
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UILabel!
    
    //Click to enter player name
    @IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: Any) {
      // textfield.text = textbox.text
        showNamePopup()
    }
    
    var listOfWords = ["mistery", "stars", "banana", "igloo", "bug", "programming", "car", "motorcycle", "weasel", "cat", "bazzinga"]
    
    let incorrectMovesAllowed = 7
    var totalWins = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }
    
    var totalLosses = 0 {
        didSet {
            newRound()
        }
    }
    
    var currentGame: Game!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newRound()
       
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
   
    func newRound() {
        if !listOfWords.isEmpty {
            let newWord = listOfWords.removeFirst()
            currentGame = Game(word: newWord, incorrectMovesRemaining: incorrectMovesAllowed, guessedLetters: [])
            enableLetterButtons(true)
            updateUI()
        } else {
            enableLetterButtons(false)
        }
    }
    
    func enableLetterButtons(_ enable: Bool) {
        for button in letterButtons {
            button.isEnabled = enable
        }
    }
    
    func updateUI() {
        var letters = [String]()
        for letter in currentGame.formattedWord {
            letters.append(String(letter))
        }
        let wordWithSpacing = letters.joined(separator: " ")
        correctWordLabel.text = wordWithSpacing
        
        scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses: \(totalLosses)"
        treeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
    }

    @IBAction func letterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isEnabled = false
        let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        let letter = Character(letterString.lowercased())
        currentGame.playerGuessed(letter: letter)
        updateGameState()
    }
    
    func updateGameState() {
        if currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining == 0 {
            totalLosses += 1
        } else if currentGame.word == currentGame.formattedWord {
            totalWins += 1
        } else {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    
        /// Pop-Up Coding
        private func showNamePopup(){
            // Make a confirmation alert dialog.
            let alert = UIAlertController(
                title: "Enter Name",
                message: "Enter player name if you wish to save progess",
                        preferredStyle: .alert
                )

            // Add a text field to get user name.
            alert.addTextField { textField in _ = textField.text}

            // Add cancel action.
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",style: .destructive, handler: { _ in} ))
               // Handle state if user cancels the pop-up.

            // Add ok action.
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok",style: .default))

            // Show pop-up. Add a completion when pop-up is destroyed.
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil );
        }
}
```

A pop-up of user input:

[image: popup]

Apple pie game:

[image: pie game]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a completion handler to the 'OK' action in your alert.

```
private func showNamePopup(){
    // Make a confirmation alert dialog.
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Enter Name",
        message: "Enter player name if you wish to save progess",
        preferredStyle: .alert
    )

    // Add a text field to get user name.
    alert.addTextField { textField in _ = textField.text}

    // Add cancel action.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",style: .destructive, handler: { _ in} ))
    // Handle state if user cancels the pop-up.

    // Add ok action.
    let okAction  = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
        if let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text {
            self?.nameLabel.text = name // Show the name in the text label
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(okAction)

    // Show pop-up. Add a completion when pop-up is destroyed.
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it.